# Apply Opacity to Sibling Paragraphs One at a Time During Scroll Animation

Tags: javascript, css

I have a figure that wraps a few paragraphs as siblings; the code for which is down below. Also, feel free to run the snippet and hover over the area.

I also have the following style rules to scroll the paragraphs up upon `figure:hover`...

```css
figure p {
    opacity:0;
    }
    
    figure:hover p {
     opacity:1;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s;
     margin: 0;
     line-height: 50px;
     text-align: center;
    
     -webkit-transform:translateY(100%);    
     transform:translateY(100%);
    
     -webkit-animation: scroll-up 5s linear infinite;
     animation: scroll-up 5s linear infinite;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes scroll-up {
     0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
     100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
    }
    @keyframes scroll-up {
     0%   { 
     -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
     transform: translateY(100%);       
     }
    50% {
     opacity:1;
    }
     100% { 
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
     transform: translateY(-100%);
     opacity:0; 
     }
    }
```

```html
    <figure class="fig_a">
                <img src="my_url"/>
                <figcaption>
                    <h2>Hover Somewhere Around Here</span></h2>
                    <p>paragraph</p>
                    <p>paragraph</p>
                    <p>paragraph</p>
                    <a href="#">View more</a>
                </figcaption>           
            </figure>
```

Note that the opacity style results in all the paragraphs becoming 100% transparent at the same time. As the post title suggests, I'm looking for a different style; one that allows for a more nuanced transition. Specifically:

**Question:** How can I have each paragraph follow its own opacity transition in tandem with its relative position in the scroll transition? In other words, paragraphs that are higher up on the page are more transparent. Likewise, paragraphs who are lower on the page are more opaque.

CSS, JS solutions are all welcome. However I am not working in a jquery environment, so I must use native JS (if JS is needed at all).

Comment: The problem is that your animation is set to ALL paragraphs. In other words, your paragraphs will have the exact same opacity as they move up. I suggest giving each paragraph a unique opacity.

Comment: I'm not opposed to assigning each paragraph its own rule, but it still has to scale reasonably well. My page has many of such figures.

Comment: Do you know what the background color behind the paragraphs is going to be?  If so, you could _fake_ the fadeout by sitting an element with a gradient of the same color as the background at the top of your scrolling container.  That way, as the paragraphs get to the top, they'll _fade_ under the gradient.

Comment: @monners that's a great idea, but unfortunately each set of paragraphs are wrapped inside a figure and an image. The image has all kinds of colors and shapes, so it'd be too tough.

Comment: Arash, You could try to use Jquery and to assign different classes. Moreover, it would be faster to use Jquery. I would write a solution but Im busy with other things.